Does a bounded positive modular sesquilinear form on a $C^\ast$-algebra induces an element of its multiplier algebra?
This is a question that originates from my attempt at this question. Specifically, for a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, I am attempting to construct a map $\phi: A \times A \to A$ s.t.,

$\phi$ is sesquilinear, i.e., it is linear in the second variable and conjugate linear in the first variable;
$\phi$ is positive, i.e., $\phi(x, x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in A$;
$\phi$ is modular, i.e., $\phi(x, ya) = \phi(x, y)a$ and $\phi(xa, y) = a^\ast \phi(x, y)$ for all $a, x, y \in A$;
$\phi$ is bounded, i.e., there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\|\phi(x, y)\| \leq C\|x\|\|y\|$.

I then plan to claim that such a $\phi$ must be of the form $(x, y) \mapsto x^\ast my$ for some $m \in M(A)_+$, where $M(A)$ is the multiplier algebra of $A$. This is the claim that I don’t know how to prove. Note that the result is obvious when $A$ is unital, in which case we easily have $\phi(x, y) = x^\ast \phi(1, 1)y$, so the interesting case is when $A$ is non-unital. I thought about using an approximate identity, but it is not clear to me why $\phi(u_\lambda, x)$ should converge when $(u_\lambda)$ is an approximate identity of $A$ and $x \in A$.
To summarize,

If $\phi: A \times A \to A$ is a bounded positive modular sesquilinear form, i.e., it satisfies conditions $1$ to $4$ as listed above, does there necessarily exist $m \in M(A)_+$ s.t. $\phi(x, y) = x^\ast my$ for all $x, y \in A$?


This is false. Any quasimultiplier that is not a multiplier will give a counterexample. Indeed, with $\psi(a,b) := \phi(a^*,b)$, you obtain a quasi-multiplier in the sense of Pedersen, which is associated to a unique element of $QM(A)$. EDIT: I see that this was answered in a comment below.

By Proposition 3.12.3 here (or Proposition 4.2 here) if $V:A\times A\to A$ is a bounded bilinear map that satisfies
$V(ab,cd)=aV(b,c)d$ for all $a,b,c,d\in A$ (those are called quasicentralizers) then there exists $m\in A^{**}$ such that $V(a,b)=amb.$  So you can define $\Phi(a,b)=V(a^*,b).$ But then, $m$ will be a "quasi-multiplier" instead of a multiplier.
*$m\in A^{**}$ is said to be quasimultiplier if $AmA\subset A.$
